# MYSQL 8 | Ubuntu 20 | Failed to start error

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, mysql-8.0

Here is the error I get. Can't start MySQL server 8 on ubuntu 20. I haven't backed up my db so can't purge all data as well. I tried reinstalling MySQL, and didn't work.

```
>/var/log/mysql/error.log 2022-08-05T08:58:15.723947Z 0 [System]
> [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.30-0ubuntu0.20.04.2)
> starting as process 19364 2022-08-05T08:58:15.762486Z 1 [System]
> [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
> 2022-08-05T08:58:16.312248Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012526] [InnoDB] Upgrade is
> not supported after a crash or shutdown with innodb_fast_shutdown = 2.
> This redo log was created with MySQL 8.0.29, and>
> 2022-08-05T08:58:16.312273Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012930] [InnoDB] Plugin
> initialization aborted with error Generic error.
> 2022-08-05T08:58:16.419203Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-010334] [Server] Failed to
> initialize DD Storage Engine 2022-08-05T08:58:16.419547Z 0 [ERROR]
> [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
> 2022-08-05T08:58:16.419593Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
> 2022-08-05T08:58:16.421968Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server]
> /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.30-0ubuntu0.20.04.2) 
> (Ubuntu).
```

The status:

```
    ● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2022-08-05 10:28:18 UTC; 23s ago
    Process: 21300 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 21308 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 21308 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
     Status: "Server shutdown complete"

Aug 05 10:28:18 srv180775 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Aug 05 10:28:18 srv180775 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 05 10:28:18 srv180775 systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
Aug 05 10:28:18 srv180775 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Aug 05 10:28:18 srv180775 systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
Aug 05 10:28:18 srv180775 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Aug 05 10:28:18 srv180775 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 05 10:28:18 srv180775 systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
```

Journalctl log:

```
-- The job identifier is 11305 and the job result is done.
Aug 05 10:29:55 srv180775 systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
-- Subject: A start job for unit mysql.service has begun execution
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- A start job for unit mysql.service has begun execution.
--
-- The job identifier is 11305.
Aug 05 10:29:56 srv180775 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
-- Subject: Unit process exited
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- An ExecStart= process belonging to unit mysql.service has exited.
--
-- The process' exit code is 'exited' and its exit status is 1.
Aug 05 10:29:56 srv180775 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
-- Subject: Unit failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- The unit mysql.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 05 10:29:56 srv180775 systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
-- Subject: A start job for unit mysql.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- A start job for unit mysql.service has finished with a failure.
--
-- The job identifier is 11305 and the job result is failed.
Aug 05 10:29:56 srv180775 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 4.
-- Subject: Automatic restarting of a unit has been scheduled
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- Automatic restarting of the unit mysql.service has been scheduled, as the result for
-- the configured Restart= setting for the unit.
Aug 05 10:29:56 srv180775 systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
-- Subject: A stop job for unit mysql.service has finished
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- A stop job for unit mysql.service has finished.
--
-- The job identifier is 11384 and the job result is done.
Aug 05 10:29:56 srv180775 systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
-- Subject: A start job for unit mysql.service has begun execution
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- A start job for unit mysql.service has begun execution.
```

Comment: Those files don't exist

Comment: I did nothing, it happened suddenly. Disk memory is 11% used